# Rails 3.1 - Thumbs_up gem missing from github.com... Where did it go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, github, rubygems

I wanted to look at the `thumbs_up` gem documentation.  All the references I see point to:  https://github.com/brady8/thumbs_up, but today I get a 404 error when I go to that URL.  Does any one know what has happened?  Has the thumbs_up gem moved somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still on [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/gems/thumbs_up), but it might not be the latest version.

edit: After more digging, it's got [quite a network](https://github.com/dfischer/thumbs_up/network) on GitHub. The most recently updated fork is by [tarnacious](https://github.com/tarnacious/thumbs_up), but [bouchard's repo](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up) is getting forked the most. bouchard seems to [update pretty regularly](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up/commits/master), so that's a good sign.